# What is the difference between NHS, HS and Slim-HS SAS Drives?

Tags: ibm, sas

I am curious to what is the practical difference, if any to the following:

- IBM 300 GB 10K 6 Gbps SAS 2.5" SFF Slim-HS HDD       42D0637
- IBM 300 GB 10K 6 Gbps  SAS 2.5" SFF HS HDD           42D0612
- IBM 300 GB 10K 6 Gbps  SAS 2.5" SFF NHS HDD          42D0627

This is as seen on the link http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=AN&subtype=CA&htmlfid=897/ENUS109-100&appname=USN#h2-keyprx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hot-swap or non-hot-swap, plus a slim one for blades.